# Ajax Toolkit Calendar Extender bold current date, ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, date, calendarextender

I am using Ajax Toolkit Calendar Extender, and i want to bold the current date, when calendar pops up.

```
var a = "1";
var b = "";

function ShowToday(e) {
    if (a == "1") {
        a = $("td.ajax__calendar_active > div").attr('id');
        a = '#' + a;
        b = a;
        $(a).css('font-weight', 'bold');
    }
    else {
        $(b).css('font-weight', 'bold');
    }
}

function CurrentDateShowing(e) {
    if (!e.get_selectedDate() || !e.get_element().value) {
        e._selectedDate = (new Date()).getDateOnly();
    }
}
```

I am uisng "CurrentDateShowing" function on OnClientShowing event, and "ShowToday" on OnClientShown event.

Currently I am using this javascript, but this script has a problem when i am switching on another month, the cell which was the cell of current date is still bold. How can I overcome this problem. And another problem, when i have two Calendar Extenders on the page this does not work. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to style the "today" element:

```
.ajax__calendar_today { font-weight: bold; }
```

Full details of the CSS classes available are on the [Samples Site](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/calendar/calendar.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your css code to change the style.
 .ajax__calendar_active : This is applied to an element in the DOM above a day, month or year and is used to apply CSS attributes that show the currently selected value.

```
.ajax__calendar_active
 {
      font-weight:bold;
 }
```

Calendar Css Classes

```
* .ajax__calendar_container : The outer rectangular container that supplies the border around the calendar element. Child Css classes: .ajax__calendar_header,.ajax__calendar_body,.ajax__calendar_footer.
* .ajax__calendar_header : A container element that holds the next and previous arrows and the title of the current view. Child Css classes: .ajax__calendar_prev, .ajax__calendar_title, .ajax__calendar_next.
* .ajax__calendar_prev : An element that displays the arrow to view the previous set of data in the view(previous month/year/decade). Child Css classes: none.
* .ajax__calendar_title : An element that displays the title of the current view (month name, year, decade). Child Css classes: none.
* .ajax__calendar_next : An element that displays the arrow to view the previous set of data in the view (previous month/year/decade). Child Css classes: none.
* .ajax__calendar_body : A container element that holds the days, months, and years panes. Also provides a fixed rectangle with hidden overflow that is used for transitioning between views (next/previous month, or days/months/years).Child Css class: .ajax__calendar_days, .ajax__calendar_months, .ajax__calendar_years.
* .ajax__calendar_days : A container element that holds the layout for the days in a month. Child Css classes: .ajax__calendar_dayname, .ajax__calendar_day
* .ajax__calendar_dayname : An element that displays the short name of the day of the week. Child Css classes: none.
* .ajax__calendar_day : An element that displays the day of the month. Child Css classes: none
* .ajax__calendar_months : A container element that holds the layout for the months in a year. Child Css classes: .ajax__calendar_month.
* .ajax__calendar_month : An element that displays the month of the year. Child Css classes: none
* .ajax__calendar_years : A container element that holds the layout for the years in a decade. Child Css classes: .ajax__calendar_year.
* .ajax__calendar_year : An element that displays the year in a decade. Child Css classes: none
* .ajax__calendar_footer : A container element that holds the current date. Child Css classes: .ajax__calendar_today.
* .ajax__calendar_today : An element that displays the current date. Child Css classes: none.
* .ajax__calendar_hover : This is applied to an element in the DOM above a day, month or year and is used to apply CSS attributes that show a hover state. Child Css classes: .ajax__calendar_day, .ajax__calendar_month, .ajax__calendar_year
* .ajax__calendar_active : This is applied to an element in the DOM above a day, month or year and is used to apply CSS attributes that show the currently selected value. Child Css classes: .ajax__calendar_day, .ajax__calendar_month, .ajax__calendar_year.
* .ajax__calendar_other : This is applied to an element in the DOM above a day or year that is outside of the current view (day not in the visible month, year not in the visible decade). Child Css classes: .ajax__calendar_day, .ajax__calendar_year.
```